# Correct way to Apply Tripundra

Tags: shiva, belief, rituals, worship, puja

I apply Tripundra on daily basis. Till now I use to make use of my Index Finger, Middle Fingure and Ring Fingure.

Today suddenly one of my friend asked:
Why we use the upper three finger only? Why not the lower one? or Thumb as well?

This lead me to do some googling, then I found some details [here](https://twitter.com/hindumediawiki/status/1342068914168057856?lang=en).

Still my question remains the same, ideally what is the correct way to use/apply Tripundra and Kumkum?

Also, any reference from our scriptures will help. Note, I am asking here about Shiva's Bhasma Tripundra.

Namah Shivay.

Comment: Yes it's correct, As per Kāmika ~ The tripundra should be marked as per the directions with the three fingers – index finger, middle finger and the ring finger.

Answer (score 3):

> 42. Two lines are to be drawn with the middle finger and the ring finger (from left end to the right end). In between those lines a line is to be drawn in the opposite direction (i.e. from right end to the left end) with the thumb. This is called Tripuṇḍra Rekhā.

[Skanda Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423679.html): Book 3 - Brāhma-khaṇḍa: Section 3 - Brāhmottara-khaṇḍa

Comment: Then what about the link which I mentioned in the Question? Does it contains incorrect details?

Answer (score 1):

> One is to hold the Tripundra, six Angulas high or greater by the fore, middle and ring fingers of the right hand. If anybody uses Tripundra, shining and brilliant, and extending from eye to eye, he becomes, no doubt, a Rudra. The ring-finger is the letter “A,” the middle finger is “U” and the forefinger is “M”; so the Tripundra marks drawn by the above three fingers is of the nature of the three gunas. The Tripundra should be drawn by the middle, fore, and ring fingers in a reverse way (from the left of the forehead to its right).
>
>  **[Srimad Devi Bhagavatham 11.15](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk11ch15.htm)**